# fade transition to a div on load

Tags: html, css

Can you apply a fade transition to a div on load using CSS only? I have a div, which initially should be transparent and after a few seconds should change to yellow. I know it is possible to do this on state change (e.g. hover). Can anyone help?

Cheers

```css
#content {
    background-color: #FF0;
    height: 100px; width: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 10000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 10000ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 10000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 10000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 10000ms linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes fadeInAnimation{
0%{
    opacity: 0;
}
100%{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

}

```
#content {
animation-name: fadeInAnimation;
animation-duration: 500ms;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
background-color: #FF0;
height: 100px; width: 100px;
-webkit-transition: background-color 10000ms linear;
-moz-transition: background-color 10000ms linear;
-o-transition: background-color 10000ms linear;
-ms-transition: background-color 10000ms linear;
transition: background-color 10000ms linear;
```

}